# TortoiseGit Commit Order

Tags: git, tortoisegit

We are currently struggling with commit graphs which look like these:

[image]

We found that if you click on the column header we can choose "Chronological reversed" and everything looks fine to us. Unfortunately tortoise git applies `--topo-order` as default which causes the commit pyramid.

Is there a way to set "Chronological revesed" as the default value?

Comment: My advice, don't use tortoise git. Tortoise is designed for CVS/SVN not GIT (no matter what the docs say). Use something like [GIT Extensions instead](https://gitextensions.github.io/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just click the **HEADER** of the commit list, then the **Log commit ordering** dialog will be popup. Select the ordering you want from there.

Here is the example for selecting **Chronological revesed**:

[image]

**[NOTE]** It's global setting, so this affects all new opened Log Message dialog.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am describing in my question.

Answer (score 0):

While there *appears* to be a setting according to the [documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-main):

> **apply --topo-order**
>   Normally log entries/commits are ordered in descending order of the commit date. '--topo-order' makes the commits appear in topological order (i.e. descendant commits are shown before their parents). Not using this option, might break the graph in the log dialog. However, this option is slower, because all log entries have to be processed before displaying them.

Neither the screenshot on that page for "Dialogs 1" settings nor does the current version show a corresponding checkbox for this and I'm not seeing any other mentions of this online.

It *looks* like there may be some code that checks for a setting, but no way to set it: [Showing 1 - 16 of 16 blobs for "--topo-order" in project TortoiseGit / TortoiseGit](https://gitlab.com/search?project_id=384627&scope=blobs&search=--topo-order)

Comment: I thought this might be a legacy entry which was not removed from docs

Comment: If you want to stick with TortoiseGit, I would suggest reporting an issue with not being able to find that setting on the screen and seeing if someone will fix it.